# ROW_NUMBER Sub Query

Tags: oracle

What is wrong with row_number when used in a sub query.

If I run the code in isolation its fine but as soon as I use it in an sub query the wrong results get returned.

```
SELECT L.CALC1,  X.APP_ID, L.CALC2,
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.APP_ID ORDER BY CALC2 DESC) R
FROM DWH_DEV.APP_CALC_REF X
CAPD_DEV.APP_LOG L
WHERE X.CALC_ID = L.CALC_ID
AND X.APP_ID = 1234;
```

Correct results:

```
CALC1 APP_ID    CAL2    R
1    1234   54321   1
1    1234   34322   2
1    1234   23123   3

SELECT CALC1, APP_ID, CALC2  FROM
(
SELECT L.CALC1, L.CALC2, X.APP_ID
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.APP_ID ORDER BY CALC2 DESC) R
FROM DWH_DEV.APP_CALC_REF X
CAPD_DEV.APP_LOG L
WHERE X.CALC_ID = L.CALC_ID
) WHERE R = 1
AND APP_ID = 1234;
```

Wrong results:

```
CALC1 APP_ID CAL2   R
1    1234   23123   1
```

I have a solution but why do I need to use it?

```
SELECT CALC1, APP_ID, CALC2  FROM
(
SELECT L.CALC1, L.CALC2, X.APP_ID
,'MAX_' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.APP_ID ORDER BY CALC2 DESC) R
FROM DWH_DEV.APP_CALC_REF X
CAPD_DEV.APP_LOG L
WHERE X.CALC_ID = L.CALC_ID
) WHERE R = 'MAX_1'
AND APP_ID = 1234;
```

Correct results:

```
CALC1 APP_ID CAL2   R
1    1234   54321   1
```

Cheers

C

Oracle version =

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: You showed us a query with `X.APP_ID = 1234` in the WHERE condition, but a result contains APP_ID = 54321, 34322 and 23123 ? Could you explain this ?

Comment: Hi, I made an arse of typing up my question.  I have made the amendment.  Cheers

Comment: Did you mean your row_number to be ordered by `calc_2 desc`, since `calc_1` is the same for all three rows? The result you get isn't really wrong, just indeterminate.

Comment: Again another typo, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: The consensus is ROW_NUMBER used in a Sub Query needs to be made deterministic or you will end up with unwanted results.

Comment: A typo in your code or when you retyped it into the question? It seems likely you've obscured the error in your actual code (I'm guessing a missing `desc`) doing that, and copy-and-pasting what you're really running and the actual results would make it easy to spot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your query is not deterministic. Results you will get depends on access path optimizer chooses (table scan, index scan, etc.)

See following example (based on HR schema).

**Setup:**

```
create table rn_test
as
select * from employees;

create index rn_test_ix on rn_test(job_id);
```

**Test1**

```
select /*+ INDEX(rn_test) */ employee_id, job_id, row_number() over(order by job_id) rn
from rn_test;
```

**Test 2**

```
select /*+ FULL(rn_test) */ employee_id, job_id, row_number() over(order by job_id) rn
from rn_test;
```

**Result 1:**

```
206 AC_ACCOUNT  1
205 AC_MGR  2
200 AD_ASST 3
100 AD_PRES 4
101 AD_VP   5
102 AD_VP   6
109 FI_ACCOUNT  7
113 FI_ACCOUNT  8
110 FI_ACCOUNT  9
....
```

**Result 2:**

```
206 AC_ACCOUNT  1
205 AC_MGR  2
200 AD_ASST 3
100 AD_PRES 4
102 AD_VP   5
101 AD_VP   6
110 FI_ACCOUNT  7
109 FI_ACCOUNT  8
113 FI_ACCOUNT  9
...
```

Comment: thanks I will have a look at this, when I get back to the office, and update with results.  Cheers